# logging exceptions to database using log4net

Tags: c#, exception, log4net

I'm currently using log4net to log my messages and exceptions to database.
I'm using this configuration:

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">

  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

  <connectionString value="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=LogDatabase;User ID=;Password=;"
                    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/ >
  </parameter>

</appender>
```

The logging is working correctly except for the fact that I'm confused about something:
If I log an exception using `log.Error(ex)` then the exception will be logged into the message column, however when I use `log.Error("Exception", ex)` then the message `Exception` will be logged to the message column while the exception will be logged to the exception column.
I would like to be able to log my exception using  `log.Error(ex)` and to have the message column empty in that case and the exception logged to the actual exception column.

Comment: When you call `log.Error(ex)`, the exception **is** the message, as that's what that method is defined as. If you don't want to just use `log.Error(null, ex)` to have an empty message, I think you will need to add a layer over `ILog` to redirect the call.

Comment: thanks @stuartd, that perfectly answered my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking at the log4net documentation you have 2 methods:

```
void Error(Object message)
void Error(Object message, Exception ex)
```

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_ILog_Error.htm
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_ILog_Error_1.htm

In both cases the first argument is the message. If you pass the exception into the message, the exception will be converted to the message (probably to string). Only the second function will fill the exception in the error log:

> ```
> exception 
>     Type: System.Exception 
>     The exception to log, including its stack trace.
> ```